# How do you speed up VBA code with a named range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a program that analyzes a worksheet (with 8000 rows and 40 columns) and returns all of the relevant product ID's but my program is unbearably slow, it takes about 5 minutes to run, so In looking for a way to speed it up I came across some code to disable screenupdating, display status bar, calculation, and events. which doubled the programs run time (from 5 to 10 minutes) But i need the program to be able to run faster still.  I kept searching and came across  [This](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel.aspx)   This seems like it's exactly what i need but i don't exactly understand how to implement it.

Let me explain what my code needs to do and maybe you can help me find a better way.  It might be helpful to tell you what the information is about.  I work for a company that sells holsters, and we are trying to find a way to gather all of the product ID's for different types of holsters for 1 gun together.  So in the first column we have the Gun names, in the 4th column we have the Holster Type and in the 12th column we have the Product ID #.

What I'm trying to do is to for any given line, make the program look throught the rest of the file and return the product ID's for the matching products (products with the exact same name) in lines 33-39  i.e column 33 will have the related concealment holster, 34 will have the related ankle holster etc.

I have already written a code to do this but how can i do it with this named DataRange Method?

```
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Location = ActiveCell.Address
    GunName = ActiveCell.Value
    X = 0
    Range("A1").Activate

    Do
        If ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0).Value = GunName Then
        PlaceHolder = ActiveCell.Address
            If ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "CA" Then
                Range(Location).Offset(0, 34).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12).Value
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "AA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "AR" Then
                If ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "NA-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "NA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "11-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "13-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-A-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-B-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-C-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-JB-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-LS-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "12-LS-b-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "11-LS-LH" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 4).Value = "21L" Then

                Else
                    Range(Location).Offset(0, 35).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12)
            End If
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "BA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "BR" Then
                Range(Location).Offset(0, 36).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12)
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "HA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "HR" Then
                Range(Location).Offset(0, 37).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12)
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "VA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "VR" Then
                Range(Location).Offset(0, 38).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12)
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "TA" Or ActiveCell.Offset(X, 3).Value = "TR" Then
                Range(Location).Offset(0, 39).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 12)
            End If
        End If
        X = X + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0).Value)
    ActiveCell.Range(Location).Activate
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
```

AA, BA CA etc are the holster types.

Comment: The technique promoted in the article is "*Range Copying*" or "*Range-Array Copying*", it has nothing to do with Named Ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT*

After viewing the sample file and clarifying through the below comments, here is the updated code.  I believe this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim GunCell As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    On Error Resume Next
    With Range("DataRange")
        .Sort .Resize(, 1), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Set rngData = .Resize(, 1)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'No data or no named range "DataRange"

    With rngData
        ReDim arrResults(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 6)
        For Each GunCell In .Cells
            If GunCell.Row > 1 Then
                ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                If LCase(GunCell.Text) <> strTemp Then
                    strTemp = LCase(GunCell.Text)
                    Set rngFound = .Find(strTemp, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
                    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                        strFirst = rngFound.Address
                        Do
                            If InStr(1, " CA BA HA VA TA ", " " & .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text & " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                Select Case UCase(.Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text)
                                    Case "CA":  cIndex = 1
                                    Case "BA":  cIndex = 3
                                    Case "HA":  cIndex = 4
                                    Case "VA":  cIndex = 5
                                    Case "TA":  cIndex = 6
                                End Select
                                arrResults(ResultIndex, cIndex) = .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Text
                            ElseIf InStr(1, " AA AR ", " " & .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text & " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
                            And InStr(1, " NA-LH NA 11-LH 13-LH 12-A-LH 12-B-LH 12-C-LH 12-JB-LH 12-LS-LH 12-LS-b-LH 11-LS-LH 21L ", " " & .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "E").Text & " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                                cIndex = 2
                                arrResults(ResultIndex, cIndex) = .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Text
                            End If
                            Set rngFound = .Find(strTemp, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
                        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
                    End If
                Else
                    For cIndex = 1 To UBound(arrResults, 2)
                        arrResults(ResultIndex, cIndex) = arrResults(ResultIndex - 1, cIndex)
                    Next cIndex
                End If
            End If
        Next GunCell
    End With

    Range("AI2:AI" & Rows.Count).Resize(, UBound(arrResults, 2)).ClearContents
    If ResultIndex > 0 Then Range("AI2").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults

End Sub
```

Comment: I use google drive, but any file hosting site that doesn't require a login will do.  Just put a link to the file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqs91eE54JBGdG5yQUpsWDA0UXVjd20xSVhVaC1CeFE&usp=sharing  I'm using column A as the Name instead of b, and the only columns that are important are A, D, M, and then the result columns which are AI through AN

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19OxvYof3EfcJCOhXFeCrc8PsSNPLlxwrXvm5X6_pC9w/edit?usp=sharing here is the original code i made btw

Comment: Thanks for your help already :), I can see the potential for this to be extremely fast, when i set the data range for the function and ran it, it only ran to about line 100, and it had the problem of always finding an answer even when there wasn't one (not every gun has a holster of a every type, as you see in the spreadsheet) but it did that in .1 seconds, which is lightning fast as far as I am concerned :)

Comment: It seems to work for me. It brings in the `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` for Holster Type `BA` and brings in `2349, 2350, 2352, 2351, 2353` for Holster Type `HA`.  It just doesn't duplicate them.  Do they need to be duplicated?

Comment: it stops at row 1388, (out of 8000) and yes they need to be repeated, each row needs to have all the associations in order for another program to read it. the example document actually is correct, there should only be a BA and an HA for the first gun etc.  Also there are BRs, HRs, etc along with the AR's. if i just changed it to be like BA/BR would that work? thanks so much :)!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6s91eE54JBGNmxlaVR3aFBBV0k/edit?usp=sharing  here is a link to the actual excel file

Comment: should my range include the result cells also? or just to the product ID #'s?

Comment: Your range should be your original table and nothing more.  So don't include the result cells, but include all columns of the original table.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH :)! how do i also accomodate the BR's CR's etc?

Comment: Increase the array size of the second dimension (the `, 1 to 6`) and then add the BR and CR checks to the appropriate `InStr` line and add them to the `Select Case` statements to give them their assigned `cIndex` number.

Comment: But I need the results for BR to go in the same cell as BA,  BA is for belt Auto and BR is Belt revolver, so they'll never overlap.  Thanks For your help :), i could've never done this on my own :).

Comment: i just added a a Case "CR": cindex = 1 and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `.Activate`, which is VERY slow and generally useless. Instead try something in this style:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sample()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If c.Offset(x, 0).Value = GunName Then
            'etc etc
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Oh ! and make sure you use `Option Explicit` and you `Dim` your variables. It's not for speed, it is to avoid errors. And use comments ;-)