# Parsing CSV file and writing data to a worksheet is slow using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, performance, csv

The following code downloads two CSV files from a website, parses the CSV files, and writes to three worksheets of a workbook.

One of the files has about 2000 records and the other has about 300 records.

If I download these CSV files and open with MS Excel, the files open instantly. But my code runs very slowly.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'initial request just to grab the cookie
    
    Dim objHttpRequest As Object
    Set objHttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    objHttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm", False
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm"
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    
    objHttpRequest.Send
    
    'store the cookie for using with consecutive requests
    Dim strNSECookie As String
    strNSECookie = objHttpRequest.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
    
'Downloading NSE ASM List (CSV file) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    'downloading the nse asm list (csv file)
    objHttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true", False
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm"
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "cookie", strNSECookie
    
    objHttpRequest.Send
    
    'parsing the csv data using split function and writing it on a woorksheet
    Dim arrNSEASMRecords As Variant
    Dim arrNSEASMRecordValues As Variant
    Dim intNSEASMRecordsCounter As Integer
    Dim intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter As Integer
    Dim strWorkSheetName As String
    Dim intNSEASMTotalRecords As Integer
    
    arrNSEASMRecords = Split(objHttpRequest.ResponseText, vbLf)
    intNSEASMTotalRecords = UBound(arrNSEASMRecords) - 1
    
    For intNSEASMRecordsCounter = 0 To intNSEASMTotalRecords Step 1
        arrNSEASMRecordValues = Split(arrNSEASMRecords(intNSEASMRecordsCounter), ",")
        
        If arrNSEASMRecordValues(0) = """Long Term""" Then
            strWorkSheetName = "LT"
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents
            intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter = 1
        ElseIf arrNSEASMRecordValues(0) = """Short Term""" Then
            strWorkSheetName = "ST"
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents
            intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter = 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(arrNSEASMRecordValues(0)) Then
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("A" & intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(0), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("B" & intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(1), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("C" & intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(2), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("D" & intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(3), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("E" & intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(4), """", "")
            
            intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter = intNSEASMSerialNumberCounter + 1
        End If
    Next intNSEASMRecordsCounter
    
'Downloading price band list (CSV file)--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Dim strNSEPBLatestFile As String
    Dim objDateCounter As Date
    
    objDateCounter = Now()
    
    'Loop to generate the latest file name and sending the request to the website
    'Mostly the latest file is of previous date but in case of holidays and weekends
    'the file maybe few more days older
    Do
        strNSEPBLatestFile = "sec_list_" & Format(objDateCounter, "ddmmyyyy") & ".csv"
        
        objHttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://archives.nseindia.com/content/equities/" & strNSEPBLatestFile, False
        objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm"
        objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
        objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "cookie", strNSECookie
        
        objHttpRequest.Send
        
        objDateCounter = DateAdd("d", -1, objDateCounter)
    Loop While objHttpRequest.Status <> 200
    
    'parsing the csv data using split function and writing it on a woorksheet
    Dim arrNSEPBRecords As Variant
    Dim arrNSEPBRecordValues As Variant
    Dim intNSEPBRecordsCounter As Integer
    Dim intNSEPBTotalRecords As Integer
    
    arrNSEPBRecords = Split(objHttpRequest.ResponseText, vbLf)
    strWorkSheetName = "Price Band"
    Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents
    intNSEPBTotalRecords = UBound(arrNSEPBRecords) - 1
    
    Debug.Print "Price band Record : " & UBound(arrNSEPBRecords)
    
    For intNSEPBRecordsCounter = 0 To intNSEPBTotalRecords Step 1
        arrNSEPBRecordValues = Split(arrNSEPBRecords(intNSEPBRecordsCounter), ",")
        
        Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("A" & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1).Value = Replace(arrNSEPBRecordValues(0), """", "")
        Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("B" & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1).Value = Replace(arrNSEPBRecordValues(1), """", "")
        Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("C" & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1).Value = Replace(arrNSEPBRecordValues(2), """", "")
        Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("D" & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1).Value = Replace(arrNSEPBRecordValues(3), """", "")
        Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("E" & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1).Value = Replace(arrNSEPBRecordValues(4), """", "")
        Application.StatusBar = "Written : " & intNSEPBRecordsCounter + 1 & " of " & intNSEPBTotalRecords
        
    Next intNSEPBRecordsCounter
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to sheet is time consuming task.
In your code, writing to sheet happens many times (since it writes cell by cell), so it is slow.
You should first writing all data to a two-dimensional array,
then copy the array to a range of sheet at a time.

Please refer the followings.

https://morsagmon.com/blog/the-huge-performance-difference-worksheet-cells-vs-arrays/

[Speed up VBA using Array with Named Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371476/speed-up-vba-using-array-with-named-range)